# How to get the Swipeable gesture value in react native

Tags: react-native

How to get the Swipeable gesture value in react native  when I swipe from left 
below code

```
<Swipeable
    renderLeftActions={LeftActions}
     onSwipeableLeftOpen={onSwipeFromLeft}
     renderRightActions={(progress, dragX) => (
    <RightActions progress={progress} dragX={dragX} onPress= 
       {onRightPress} />
      )}
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

For any one else looking for an answer without using an external package. React native now have something called [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

In my Case I needed to know if the user **swiped up or down**. Same goes to left or right but instead you get `e.nativeEvent.pageX` and this what worked for me.

There is also `e.nativeEvent.locationY` and `e.nativeEvent.locationX` which could be handy for a specific actions I think, but didn't need it here

```
const [inPageY, setInPageY] = useState(0)

<Pressable
      onPress={(e): void => {
        if (inPageY > e.nativeEvent.pageY) {
         //do something...
        } else if (inPageY < e.nativeEvent.pageY) {
          //do something...
        }
      }}
      onPressIn={(e): void => {
        setInPageY(e.nativeEvent.pageY)
      }}
    >
           // Some View.... 

</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `react-native-swipe-gestures` (https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures) which provides good support on the basic 4 directional swipes (up, down, left, right)

You could use it as such:

```
import GestureRecognizer from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';

<GestureRecognizer
    onSwipe={swipeHandler}
    onSwipeLeft={leftSwipeHandler}
    onSwipeRight={rightSwipeHandler}
    onSwipeUp={upSwipeHandler}
    onSwipeDown={downSwipeHandler}
>
    ...swipable area...
</GestureRecognizer>
```

The “onSwipe” method calls a function with the parameters `(gestureName, gestureState)` and is used for all swipe actions. All the other one direction specific onSwipe methods call a function with the `gestureState` parameter.

gestureName is the basic thing you can use to tell which direction has been swiped in, and can be any of the following values: SWIPE_UP, SWIPE_DOWN, SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT, and null (for any other type of swipe)